# Can't access to production endpoint with WSO2 API Manager - entreprise proxy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying wso2 api manager for my team.

When i follow the [quick start guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM170/Quick+Start+Guide), I can't get a good production endpoint in the implement part.
It's the same for wsdl

I think it's because I have the api manager on my computer, and this computer is behind a entreprise proxy.
I search on the documentation and on stack overflow but I don't understand how I can say  carbon to use the proxy.

If you have an idea of how I can configure AM to use an entreprise proxy, I will be very happy

I don't know if its can help : I can't acces to the api manager whitout using localhost or 127.0.0.1:9443

Thanks !

Comment: You want to use any host name? eg: www.abc.com

Comment: not for the moment.

I find in the ESB documentation, that I should change the axis2.xml file.
I change it with this : 

`<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSender">

        <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
  
<parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">abcd.proxy.com</parameter>
  
<parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">8080</parameter>
   
 </transportSender>
`

but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the following configuration changes to tell API Manager (APIM) to talk to the Web proxy. Restart APIM for the config changes to take effect.

Edit the following file:

```
  <APIM Home>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml
```

Add the follow lines in two places:

```
<parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">proxyName.company.com</parameter>
<parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">1234</parameter>
<parameter name="http.nonProxyHosts" locked="false">localhost</parameter>
```

Near line 483, add the 3 new lines, such that is looks like this when you’re done:

```
<transportSender name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender">
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">proxyName.company.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">1234</parameter>
    <parameter name="http.nonProxyHosts" locked="false">localhost</parameter>
</transportSender>
```

Near line 528, add the 3 new lines, such that is looks like this when you’re done:

```
<transportSender name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSSLSender">
    <parameter name="non-blocking" locked="false">true</parameter>
    <parameter name="http.proxyHost" locked="false">proxyName.company.com</parameter>
    <parameter name="http.proxyPort" locked="false">1234</parameter>
    <parameter name="http.nonProxyHosts" locked="false">localhost</parameter>
    <parameter name="keystore" locked="false">
            <KeyStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
                <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
            </KeyStore>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="truststore" locked="false">
            <TrustStore>
                <Location>repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks</Location>
                <Type>JKS</Type>
                <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
            </TrustStore>
        </parameter>
        <!--<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">DefaultAndLocalhost</parameter>-->
            <!--supports Strict|AllowAll|DefaultAndLocalhost or the default if none specified -->
    </transportSender>
```

Restart APIM for the config changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks a lot to your try.
At then, I think it doesn't work because it's a reverse proxy or something like that.
Thank you very much

Comment: how do you specify username & password for proxy server?

Answer (score 0):

- You need to edit carbon.xml Host parameter if you want to access management console with a host name. (And particular host entry should be resolved with a DNS name, else you can edit hosts file too)
- If you want to pass the traffic via a proxy server then you need to do [like this](http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2012/11/configuring-wso2esb-to-pass-messages.html);
  In axis2 configuration , at the transport sender configuration two properties has to be provided.
  http.proxyHost : Proxy server's IP 
  http.proxyPort : Prosy server's port

Comment: Thanks to help me. 

I'm on my computer and I don't have a DNS name for my server so I use my Ip adress in carbon.xml : `<HostName>10.123.123.123</HostName>`    ...     

I modify the axis2.xml like you say : http.proxyHost should be an ip adress ? can't be a DNS name ?

      ...    

but after I don't really understand : I should modify this file ? : `wso2am-1.7.0\repository\deployment\server\synapse-configs\default\synapse.xml` and add my proxy adress ?

Thanks a lot to help me