# Getting Response code 0 in API manager wso2 while Trying to connect Through enterprise Proxy

Tags: api, proxy, wso2, http-proxy, wso2-api-manager

Well ,

i m hitting a simple PhoneVerify Request from my localhost which have enterprise proxy .

i have configured my Proxy setting using below link.

[Can't access to production endpoint with WSO2 API Manager - entreprise proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270323/cant-access-to-production-endpoint-with-wso2-api-manager-entreprise-proxy)

But I m Getting The Same Response code 0 and Blank Response Body.

Here Is a the curl and Request URL :

Curl

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "Authorization: Bearer b9d93ac569bec1721716e1422b852b"  "https://192.168.78.153:8244/phone/1.0.0/CheckPhoneNumber?PhoneNumber=8888888888&LicenseKey=0"
```

Request URL

```
https://192.168.78.153:8244/phone/1.0.0/CheckPhoneNumber?PhoneNumber=8888888888&LicenseKey=0
```

**Response Body**

no content

**Response Code**

0

Response Headers

```
{
  "error": "no response from server"
}
```

[ base url: /phone/1.0.0 , api version: 1.0.0 ]

Answer (score 0):

Since you are behind a proxy with port set through `http.proxyPort`, You have to use port 1234 instead of 8244.

Comment: Where do i need to make Change in this case...??