# Swagger UI returns "no content" in the Response Body, and Response Code 0

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm newer to **Swagger UI**.  I use swagger with **Json**. When the response is also **Json**. When clicking **Try it Out**, I see a correct Request `URL`, but the **Swagger UI** returns `"no content"` in the **Response Body**, and **Response Code** `0`.

[image: Swagger]

Mentioned that **API's URL** is not **publicly** accessible, but the site that hosts the **Swagger UI** is in the same network as the site that hosts the API.

I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990365/getting-response-code-0-in-api-manager-wso2-while-trying-to-connect-through-ente) stack overflow question, but not found the solution.

**My Swagger.Json file:**

```
{
    "swagger": "2.0",
    "info": {
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "title": "Swagger for Rest API",
        "description": "A sample API that uses a application as an example to demonstrate features in the swagger-2.0 specification",
        "termsOfService": "http://helloreverb.com/terms/",
        "contact": {
            "name": "Swagger API team",
            "email": "abc@gmail.com",
            "url": "http://xxxx.com"
        },
        "license": {
            "name": "MIT",
            "url": "http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT"
        }
    },
    "host": "localhost:85xx",
    "basePath": "/v1",
    "schemes": [
        "http"
    ],
    "consumes": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "produces": [
        "application/json"
    ],
    "paths": {
        "/test/{username}/{albumname}/{imagename}": {
            "get": {
                "description": "Returns all images from the system that the user has access to",
                "operationId": "findface",
                "produces": [
                    "application/json",
                    "application/xml"
                ],
                "parameters": [
                    {
                        "name": "username",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "tags to filter by",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "albumname",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "maximum number of results to return",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "imagename",
                        "in": "path",
                        "description": "maximum number of results to return",
                        "required": true,
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ],
                "responses": {
                    "200": {
                        "description": "OK",
                        "schema": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/definitions/test1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "default": {
                        "description": "unexpected error",
                        "schema": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/errorModel"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "definitions": {
        "test1": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "id",
                "name"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int64"
                },
                "name": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "tag": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        },
        "errorModel": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": [
                "code",
                "message"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "code": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "format": "int32"
                },
                "message": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please can any one help.
Thank in Advance.

Comment: Can you open your browser debug console and share whatever error is shown there?

Comment: any solution you got. I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be a CORS issue. You should add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` into response headers.

Please refer: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/README.md#cors-support

Answer (score 0):

It should be a CORS issue. You should add Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * into response headers.

Use this code in the startup class

// global cors policy

```
 app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());
```